# $x^{10}$ or $e^{x-2}$ , which grows faster?

Tags: calculus, limits, related-rates

I am trying to solve a limit and I need to understand which grows faster between $x^{10}$ and $e^{x-2}$.

I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^a}=\infty$ but how can I prove that  $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^{x-2}}{x^a}=\infty$.I would go for a substitution where $t=x-2$, but I am not sure about it. Plus, what happens if there is a constant? How can I prove that for some $k>0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{e^{x-2}}{Kx^a}=0$, that is for some constant this quantity goes to 0. Maybe this cannot happen, but, even in this case, how could I prove so? Thank you for your time.

Comment: tried L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Limits with exponential functions are usually introduced after L'Hopital's Rule, so you should be able to use that.

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{x-2}}{x^a} = \frac{1}{e^2}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{x^a} = \infty$ since a constant multiplied by a limit to infinity still gives infinity. 

Basically for these kinds of questions, we are dealing with very large $x$ (larger than any number you can think of), so $e^x$ and $e^{x-2}$ behave similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x-2}}{x^a} = \frac{1}{e^2}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{x^a} = \infty$$
Again
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{Kx^a} = \frac{1}{K}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{x^a} = \infty$$

Just  rememeber that the exponential function grows faster than $x^a$ for any $a$. A more intuitive way to see this is to note that
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$
So, no matter what $a$ you take, just take any integer let's say $n>a$ and note that $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is in the series expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sayan Dutta

Comment: @AlexD'ago You're welcome!